# Android Studio Calculator

Tags: java, android, string, substring, calculator

Here is my Code for Calculator

But when the C button is pressed the last character of the equation window

gets changed to C which should not occur.

Please help me to get the code correct
[The image shows the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHQvV.png)

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        MaterialButton button = (MaterialButton) view;
        String buttonText = button.getText().toString();
        String dataToCalculate = equation.getText().toString();

        if(buttonText.equals("AC")){
            equation.setText("");
            result.setText("0");
            return;
        }
        if(buttonText.equals("C")) {
            dataToCalculate = dataToCalculate.substring(0, dataToCalculate.length() - 1);
        }
        if(buttonText.equals("=")){
            equation.setText(result.getText());
            return;
        }else{
            dataToCalculate = dataToCalculate + buttonText;
        }
        equation.setText(dataToCalculate);

        String finalResult = getReasult(dataToCalculate);

        if(!finalResult.equals("ERROR")){
            result.setText(finalResult);
        }
    }
```

I have no idea why the letter C is getting printed.

please help me configure the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code enters first condition `if(buttonText.equals("C"))` , which is fine and works as excepted.

Next statement is again `if` statement with `else` case , and code tries to execute the same.(below code is executed).

```
if(buttonText.equals("=")){
    equation.setText(result.getText());
    return;
}else{
    dataToCalculate = dataToCalculate + buttonText;
}
```

`dataToCalculate = dataToCalculate + buttonText;` this line adds the char C to your text.

Use `else if` or `switch` to handle this, or add `return` in `if case (if(buttonText.equals("C")))` as you have done for other if conditions.

Use debugger, you will get better idea what's happening.